# Unable to store special characters in Oracle 11g Database

Tags: database, oracle, encoding, utf-8, character

I am unable to store special characters like ÐÇ¶Ą§å in oracle 11g database, it shows the stored information as ??????. I have used UTF-8 encoding through out, and also checked the database for the supported charactersets using

```
select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET%';
```

it gives the output

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16
```

Is there any way of storing those special characters in database?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you are failing to store them? Much more likely, you are having trouble displaying them. Try dumping hex and see if they look reasonable.

Comment: Yes I am sure. I know about the displaying problem. I can identify those characters by the corresponding codes in oracle.

Comment: Well, then you better post the code you use to store the data in Oracle, or no one is going to be able to help you here.

Answer (score -1):

convert them into binary and then store them in bfile

Comment: Converting string into binary can be done easily but the main task is to retrieve the original string back from that binary.

Comment: you can retrieve the binary file again and convert it to string, let me know what else is your requirement